# NFC How to listen the behavior of NdfMessage push complete

Tags: android, nfc

I am using API level 10 to develop App with NFC

I want to listen when does the NdfMessage is pushed complete

but the interface NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback is for API level 14

so does it have another method to listen the behavior of push NdfMessage?

Comment: Not that I am aware of..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is not way in API 10 to check whether the NDEF transfer was successful.